# Need to open a new window with Javascript and pass query strings stored in a string variable in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I may be going about this all wrong but I am trying to set up a normal HTML button on the client side, using javascript and `Window.Open` to determine the page url, size, position, etc.

What I would like to do is pass local variables from code-behind and some how attach the query string segment to the url within the `Window.Open` script dynamically. What I was thinking of doing is constructing the query string in the code behind and assign it to a string variable. I would the like to simply attached the variable from code-behind to the query string segment of the url, in the `Window.Open` script.

**Something like this, although I this isn't working...**

```
<input type="button" value="Printer Friendly Copy" onclick="window.open('Print.aspx?<%= MyString %>', '_blank', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400')" />
```

Could anyone tell me the proper way of doing this? I could navigate to a new page all together using `Response.Redirect` in code-behind but I would prefer to open a new window and so far, javascript seems to be the best way of doing this from my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your value in the code-behind into a hidden field with a unique name or class.  On the client side, use javascript/jquery to find that hidden field and then use window.open passing it the query string key/value.

For example, `var vals = $('#myHiddenField').val();` in jquery notation.  or use getElementById in js.

HTH

Comment: I suppose I could create a hidden label on the page_load even with a per-determined parameters and pass the label text value with JS.

Comment: This got it. I'm able to first assign my parameter data to a hidden label and the read the label text with my JS function. `<script type="text/javascript">
    function NewPrintWindow()
    {
        var QueryParameters = $('<%= hlReceiptData %>').val()
        Window.Open("Print.aspx?" + QueryParameters, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400")}

</script>`

Comment: In code behind, I assign the hidden label's text as.. `            string ReceiptData = "PatientFirstName=" + PatientFirstNameLabel.Text + "&"
            + "PatientLastName=" + PatientLastNameLabel.Text + "&";
            hlReceiptData.Text = ReceiptData.ToString(); `

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but if you simply want to open a new window with a url that contains parameters, that is certainly possible.

Note that you must open the new window *only* in response to a UI event, like a button click, or the browser will assume it's malicious and block it.

My question is what you are doing with

```
<%= MyString %>
```

is that a variable you want to fill in? If so, you should simply construct the url in Javascript.

```
var url = "Print.aspx?" + variables;
window.open(url, ...)
```

Here is a simple fiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/LvB7Z/1/

Comment: That makes perfect sense. What I'm trying to to though is construct the parameters dynamically according to certain conditions in code-behind. I guess I'm trying to associate a C# variable with JavaScript, filling in the parameters with the C# variable values. I'm a bit flaky with it comes to JS though.